# Use a repository method in a custom repository implementation

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot 3 and spring data jpa.

I created a repostiory, a custom repository and it's implementation.

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long>, CustomInvoiceRepository {

       Invoice findByIdEditorLike (Long idEditor);

}

public interface CustomInvoiceRepository {
    List<Invoice> getInvoicesByIdEditor(Long idEditeur);
}


public class CustomInvoiceRepositoryImpl implements CustomInvoiceRepository{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<String> getInvoicesByIdEditor(Long idEditeur) {

        List<DestinataireAvis> listDest = findByIdEditorLike(idEditeur);
        ....
    }
}
```

In the implementation, how do I call the method in the repository?

Comment: Why not use a simpler HSQL query like `@Query("SELECT i FROM Invoice i WHERE i.idEditor = ?1 ") List<Invoice> getInvoicesByIdEditor(Long idEditeur);`?

Comment: because there is a lot of other stuff who need to be done in getInvoicesByIdEditor

Comment: It would be helpful to know what other things you'd do there. As it is, the answer would be to "just write the actual logic the repository is supposed to do", but I doubt that's why you are asking. Is it some kind of serialization or mapping?. Also, I'd suggest fix the return types in your code snippet. I understand they are more likely for example purposes, but they all are mixed up and can be misleading/confusing.

Comment: Question is In the implementation, I need to do a call to a method in the repository?

Comment: inject `InvoiceRepository` to your class that you want to call and then call it's methods.

Comment: @muhammedozbilici that will create a circular reference